# VBA in Access. How to require a field if another field has been answered

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on an Access DB and need to require that ScrapAmount1 has an answer if they have put data into ScrapCodes1. I want to have an error message pop up that reminds them to make the amount of scrap higher than 0. I'm using VBA and here is what I have that is not working. PS. ScrapCodes1 is a drop down list that they choose from and the ScrapAmount is 0 by default.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.ScrapCodes1 Then
     If Nz(Me.ScrapAmount1, "") = "" Then
          Cancel = True
          MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value.", vbExclamation, "Data Required"
     End If
End If

End Sub

Thank you for your answers in advance. :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need anything more than:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     If Me.ScrapAmount1= 0 Then
          Cancel = True
          MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value.", vbExclamation, "Data Required"
     End If      
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Random_answer_guy! Thank you for your answer! That works great!  I used this code and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much! 

`Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     If Me.ScrapAmount1= 0 Then
          Cancel = True
          MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value.", vbExclamation, "Data Required"
     End If      
End Sub`

Comment: Yes it isn't conditional because of the default value, it will never be null. However, it may be better to remove the default value (since 0 is in fact a value) and then change the check to `If IsNull(Me.ScrapAmount) Then` and then prompt for a proper value.

Comment: Just an heads up, this will throw an error if he deletes the default 0 and doesn't input a new number (returning a null). You should account for that possibility somewhere, either on the code of the textbox (forcing the user to input a number, or turning nulls to 0), or when reading the value (again accounting for the possibility of null).

Answer (score 0):

Your if is using the Nz to check if ScrapAmount1 is null. ScrapAmount1 defaults to 0, so it's not null.

I'd have a second If condition myself:

```
'check for null
If Nz(Me.ScrapAmount1, "") = "" Then
      Cancel = True
      MsgBox "If Scrap Code is selected, then Scrap Amount must have a value.", vbExclamation, "Data Required"
'checks for 0 and negative numbers
ElseIf Me.ScrapAmount1 <= 0 then
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox "Scrap Amount must be higher than 0"
End If

If Cancel then
    'do cancel stuff, I have no idea what you use this var for
end if
```

Comment: Hi CyberClaw. Thank you for the answer! That makes sense that my default "0" would make the field not empty. I tried your code and it gives me an error that says **Compile Error: Must be first statement on the line** and the code line 'Else If Me.ScrapAmount1 <= 0 Then' Lights up red. I tried it without the Else and it still gave me a compile error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In VBA it's `elseif` (one word) and `end if` (separate words). I tend to mix them up. The better way to remember `elseif` is together, it's because it's used only for `if`, so it's just 1 command. `end`, on the other hand is used for many things, so `end` if is separate because the command `end` can be used for `if`, `sub`, etc.